# expression is "optimized out" even with debug compile flags

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

My compile flags are

```
-mthumb -mlittle-endian -x c++ -gdwarf-2 -g3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fnothrow-opt 
-ffreestanding  -fverbose-asm   -std=c++11 -c -fno-rtti -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
-fno-exceptions`
```

Note the `-gdwarf-2 -g3`

However, many of the variables I attempt to read are read as

```
optimized out
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] and tell us what your toolchain is?

Comment: Add `-O0` to that and ditch `-fomit-frame-pointer`. For starters.

Answer (score 2):

`-g` adds debugging information, but it does not discourage code optimisations, so you've only asked for half the job.

Add on `-O0` or `-Og` and have a read of [the manual page on debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options).

You've also specifically turned on one optimisation ([`-fomit-frame-pointer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)); remove that.